# How to filter + select json inside Jsonfield in django-rest-framwork

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

In one column response is store like this.

I have this model.py:

```
class Form(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    children = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This is my views.py file:

```
class FormAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Form.objects.all()
        queryset = queryset.filter(children__contains=[{"id": "propertyName#0"}])
```

I have tried this, but didn't get expected output.

Now I want to filter this response

```
[
    {
        "id": "A",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "propertyName#0",
                "index": 0,
                "label": "Property",
            },
            {
                "id": "userName#0",
                "index": 1,
                "label": "Reported By",
            },
            {
                "id": "textinput#0",
                "index": 2,
                "label": "Reported By Title",
            },
            {
                "id": "dateinput",
                "index": 3,
                "label": "Date Reported",
            }
        ],
        "component": "sectionDivider"
    },
    {
        "id": "B",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "propertyName#0",
                "index": 0,
                "label": "Property",
            },
            {
                "id": "userName#0",
                "index": 1,
                "label": "Reported By",
            },
            {
                "id": "textinput#0",
                "index": 2,
                "label": "Reported By Title",
            },
            {
                "id": "dateinput",
                "index": 3,
                "label": "Date Reported",
            }
        ],
        "component": "sectionDivider"
    },
    {
        "id": "C",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "propertyName#0",
                "index": 0,
                "label": "Property",
            },
            {
                "id": "userName#0",
                "index": 1,
                "label": "Reported By",
            },
            {
                "id": "textinput#0",
                "index": 2,
                "label": "Reported By Title",
            },
            {
                "id": "dateinput",
                "index": 3,
                "label": "Date Reported",
            }
        ],
        "component": "sectionDivider"
    }
]
```

I want to filter like this. How can I get this response?

I have id for the check like id: "A", id :"B" should only filter A and B and inside A and B i also want to filter.

```
[
    {
        "id": "A",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "propertyName#0",
                "index": 0,
                "label": "Property",
            }
        ],
        "component": "sectionDivider"
    },
    {
        "id": "B",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "propertyName#0",
                "index": 0,
                "label": "Property",
            },
            {
                "id": "userName#0",
                "index": 1,
                "label": "Reported By",
            }
        ],
        "component": "sectionDivider"
    }
]
```

So far, I have tried django orm but I'm unable to get expected output

Comment: in expected response there will be multiple children or single children

Answer (score 0):

Django ORM does provide [support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#key-index-and-path-transforms) for nested queries inside the `JSONField`.

Assuming your JSON field is defined like this:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ....
    parent = JSONField()
```

The desired results can be achieved by using the ORM and the [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#std-fieldlookup-contains) lookup:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(
    parent__contains=[{"id":"A", "children": [{"label": "Property"}]}, {"id":"B"}]
)
```

It's quite powerful and allows you to do nested filtering as well.
See how I used the `children:label` filter along with the `id` filter.

Comment: but here i have two columns one is id and other is children so if i search or want to get 
"id": "propertyName#0", than i need to get response with id columns and children columns data as well where this id: propertyname#0 consists and ignore all the fields and children. 

for example shown in above case.

you are considering only one parent columns, i have two id and children and need to form response with id and children.

Comment: Provided that you have updated the question with more clarity now. I believe it is not possible if we just stay in the ORM world. The filters are applied to include/exclude the matching rows.
I'd suggest doing this filtering on the python-level if performance is not a big concern.